# Always upvoting a question that "Looks OK"

Tags: discussion, upvotes, triage

What is the consensus on upvoting a question that gets three "Looks OK" clicks on the Triage queue? I automatically do it if I am the third person to give a "Looks OK" decision. Why would I not upvote a question that "Looks OK"?

I may be asking this question with badges like [electorate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate) in mind.

Comment: You might note upvote if you had already run out of votes!

Comment: :) You mean for a day? We'll lets say I am starting the day afresh and the only activity I will have on stack overflow that day is 20 triage queue reviews.......

Comment: A question "that looks ok" can still be good or bad, interesting, trivial, etc. For me the "Looks OK" is usually only the form of the question. Are there typos/grammar issues, badly formatted code, etc? The question itself may be trivial or otherwise bad, but if it fits the criteria of SO, I'll click "Looks OK", even though a question may "Look OK", I still up- or downvote it, depending on whether I think it is a good question or not.

Comment: I'm not sure about down voting a question that I just said "Looks OK" never mind leaving it sit.

Comment: You should vote up *good* questions. If it looks OK, I'd say don't vote.

Comment: Why is the option there then?

Comment: @adrianmann Becasuse *many* of the posts that pass through the queue are going to not just meet the minimum standards, but exceed them and truly be quality content.  They won't *all* be that good, but enough of them will that the feature was added.  If they felt that *all* posts that meet that minimum standard should be upvoted then you wouldn't be given a choice; the upvote would just be applied automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you "looks okay" a question in a review queue, what you're saying is that, "this post doesn't require moderation action."

When you upvote a post you're saying that it's quality, useful content.

Those two things aren't the same.

A Triage question might not have problems so significant as to merit closure, and it might not have presentation problems that would require the assistance of an editor, but just not be an inherently useful, interesting, and well researched question.

You're "looks okay"-ing a question when it meets the *minimum* standards for a question.  You're saying that it's not *so bad that we have to get rid of it*, or even so bad that we need to fix it up before we can let people see it.  An upvote isn't just there to say, "this meets the lowest possible bar", it's a way of saying that it is a *quality* post.

Comment: Cool, I will keep this in mind, Thanks Servy!